# USART2 платы Nucleo_L152RE не выводит текст на PuTTY

Tags: putty

Я создал в STM32CubeMX простейший проект, чтобы вывести текст на экран посредством PuTTY. Но на PuTTY ничего не выводится, я наблюдаю пустой экран с курсором. Хотя на другой такой же плате ( у меня их две одинаковых ) все работает. Что я делаю не так ? Вот мой код :

```
    int main(void){
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    uint8_t SendBuf[]="Slave Send";
    uint8_t ReceiveBuf[11];
    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();
    MX_SPI1_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
        while (1){

        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
            HAL_UART_Transmit( &huart2, "Reseiving from Master\r\n", 23, 100);

            //HAL_SPI_Receive( &hspi1, ReceiveBuf, 11, 100);

            //HAL_UART_Transmit( &huart2, "Received : ", 12, 100);
            //HAL_UART_Transmit( &huart2, ReceiveBuf, 11, 100);
            //HAL_UART_Transmit( &huart2, "\r\n", 3, 100);

        }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец то я догадался взглянуть на обратную сторону платы. Оказывается, джамперы SB13 и SB14, отвечающие за связь с ST-LINK выпаяны, и припаяны на SB62 и SB63. Завтра на работе перепаяю и проверю, решило ли это проблему.